# R ROI_solve error

Tags: r, cplex, glpk, r-optimization

I am not able to find the R package "ROI.plugin.cplex" anywhere.
Any ideas how to get that package?
I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and R version 3.2.2

I tried

```
install.packages("ROI.plugin.cplex", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Comment: hmm... the tar.gz file does not exist when i select it manually from here https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=308

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite old question but since it seems unanswered. There exist 3 main sources for ROI packages [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROI/index.html), [R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/roi/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/cran/ROI). ROI.plugin.cplex can be found on CRAN (don't know how this was 3 years ago).

Installation instructions for the plugins can be found at 
http://roi.r-forge.r-project.org/installation.html.

Since gurobi and mosek publish their R bindings not on CRAN but on their own homepage,
also ROI.plugin.gurobi and ROI.plugin.mosek can not be put on CRAN. They are available via R-Forge or Github. For example

```
install.packages("ROI.plugin.gurobi", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
## or (recommended version)
remotes:::install_svn("svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/roi/pkg/ROI.plugin.gurobi")
## or
remotes:::install_github("FlorianSchwendinger/ROI.plugin.gurobi")
```